# TabLayout cannot be cast to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2

Tags: android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm trying the build a TabLayout inside a fragment.
Originally the tab layout was made in an Acitvtie, but I modified the code to make it work in a fragment.

```
11/23 15:56:40: Launching 'app' on Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE API 22.
Install successfully finished in 3 s 16 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.ssl.app/com.ssl.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 22349 on device 'Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_S7_FE_API_22 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10097: Read-only file system
W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb40f16f0, tid 22349
D/Atlas: Validating map...
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae85f2e0, tid 22367
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae834d00: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834d00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae839400)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834d00: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xae839400)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ssl.app, PID: 22349
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout cannot be cast to androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        at com.ssl.app.ui.tablayout.TabLayoutFragment.onCreateView(TabLayoutFragment.java:32)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:538)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**TabLayoutFragment.class**

```
    package com.ssl.app.ui.tablayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.ssl.app.R;
//import com.ssl.app.R;

public class TabLayoutFragment extends Fragment {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tablayout,container,false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager2 = (ViewPager2) root.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                tabLayout.getTabAt(position).select();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

**MyViewPagerAdapter.class**

```
package com.ssl.app.ui.tablayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    public MyViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentAlpha();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentBeta();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentCharlie();
            case 3:
                return new FragmentDelta();
            default:
                return new FragmentAlpha();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

**fragment_tablelayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.tablayout.TabLayoutFragment" >

    <!-- TabLayout -->
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout">
        <!-- TABS -->
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Alpha"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Beta"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Charlie"/>
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delta"/>
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    <!-- ViewPager -->
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
package com.ssl.app;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.ssl.app.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
     setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_Stocklist, R.id.nav_Settings)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I probably overlooked something

Comment: `viewPager2 = (ViewPager2) root.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);` - Typo. You meant to use `R.id.view_pager` there.

Comment: you entered the same id of the tab layout instead of viewPager id.